# Did anyone succeded with running 'rippled'?

Tags: ripple, rippled

I made an attempt to run [rippled](https://developers.ripple.com/build-run-rippled-ubuntu.html) both versions 1.1.2 and 1.2.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 and I would not say it does not work at all, because it utilizes CPU and Disk, creates database of 3GB size, and I even was able to create a wallet from the command line, but if I do

```
./rippled account_info r9cZA1mLK5R5Am25ArfXFmqgNwjZgnfk59 true
```

I always get

```
Loading: "/home/xrp/.config/ripple/rippled.cfg"
2019-May-29 10:04:10.273909186 HTTPClient:NFO Connecting to 127.0.0.1:5005

{
   "result" : {
      "error" : "lgrNotFound",
      "error_code" : 21,
      "error_message" : "ledgerNotFound",
      "request" : {
         "account" : "r9cZA1mLK5R5Am25ArfXFmqgNwjZgnfk59",
         "command" : "account_info",
         "ledger_index" : 0
      },
      "status" : "error"
   }
}
```

What can be wrong?

See [Building and running rippled on Ubuntu](https://developernote.com/2019/01/building-and-running-rippled-on-ubuntu/) for more information on what steps I did.

**EDIT1**:

I tried the same account_info command with s1.ripple.com and s2.ripple.com and got the same "lgrNotFound" error:

./rippled -v --rpc_ip 34.213.185.56:51234 account_info r9cZA1mLK5R5Am25ArfXFmqgNwjZgnfk59 true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are successfully running rippled. What you haven't done yet is successfully get rippled up-to-date or "synchronized" to the rest of the nodes on the network.

There are several possible reasons why, but these are the most common that I've seen:

1. Inability to connect to other peers. If your firewall or other network issue is making it impossible to connect to other peers, you're never going to sync. Run `rippled server_info`, and look for the number of `peers`. It should be at least 10 after rippled has been running for a few minutes. (The command `rippled peers` will give a lot more detail, but usually the number is sufficient to know if you're ok or not.)
2. Insufficient time. It can take several minutes for a node to sync, because it has to download the state of the ledger at some given time, then catch up to the changes from that time. If you've been waiting over 15 minutes or so, this is probably not your problem.
3. Insufficient machine resources. Most often this takes the form of a slow network connection, or a slow hard drive. These pages will give more details and current recommendations:

   - https://developers.ripple.com/system-requirements.html
   - https://developers.ripple.com/capacity-planning.html
4. Inability to download the validator list. Less common in general is a problem connecting to the cofigured `[validator_list_sites]` (https://vl.ripple.com) by default. Run `rippled validators`. You should get a result that includes a bunch (31 currently) of validator node IDs (50-odd character strings starting with "n"), and a JSON object labelled `validator_list`. That object should indicate an expiration date in the future, and a status of "active". Anything else usually indicates a problem. `rippled validator_list_sites` may give you more of an explanation of what the problem is, if any.

Comment: 1. I have 10 peers all the time, see https://developernote.com/2019/01/building-and-running-rippled-on-ubuntu/#peers . Is this enough? Should the peers port 51235 be accessible from the internet for incoming connections? (currently on my machine it is not). 2. About the time, I kept ripped running for several days. 3. I have SSD, 16GB RAM, but probably a slow CPU Celeron 2.8GHz with 2 cores. The internet connection is at least 0.5MB/sec. 4. I will investigate this.

Comment: I opened port 51235 for incoming connections and now I have about 20 peers.

Comment: Currently there are 31 validator nodes IDs (50-odd character strings starting with “n”), the status is “active”, but the expiration date is not in future: at the moment of running the command the server date/time was 2019-Jul-17 12:42:16 UTC, but the expiration date was 2019-Jul-17 00:00:00, see full command output here: https://developernote.com/2019/01/building-and-running-rippled-on-ubuntu/#validators

Comment: I think you have a typo in the current date above. As of right now, it's June 18, and the list expires around July 17, which is in the future. Also I notice that the `validator_list_sites` indicates that the most recent download of the list was in June, too: `"last_refresh_time" : "2019-Jun-17 13:02:46.055804293"`.

The `server_info` you posted there shows that your node is synchronized and validating. `"server_state" : "proposing",`. Any `validated_ledger` age under about 7 seconds indicates that you are more-or-less keeping up with the network. Try that `account_info` command again.

Comment: I was able to run 'account_info' command with JSON-RPC using curl, see https://developernote.com/2019/01/building-and-running-rippled-on-ubuntu/#curl, but account_info from the command line still fails with the same error. Also see EDIT1 - the command fails not only with my local rippled node, but also with s1.ripple.com.

Comment: It turns out that I missed the actual root cause of your problem. Our command line documentation is not entirely clear:
`account_info <account>|<seed>|<pass_phrase>|<key> [<ledger>] [strict]`
Would make it seem that you could leave out the ledger and only specify `strict`, but you can't. So the reason it's failing with your command line is that it's interpreting "true" as the `ledger` value. Also, the `strict` field is looking only for the word "strict", so "true" won't work anyway.

Try running just `./rippled account_info r9cZA1mLK5R5Am25ArfXFmqgNwjZgnfk59`.

Comment: PS. If you try to run `./rippled account_info r9cZA1mLK5R5Am25ArfXFmqgNwjZgnfk59 current strict`, you will not get any results at all. This looks like a bug in the command line parser.

Comment: Another correction: You _can_ run `./rippled account_info r9cZA1mLK5R5Am25ArfXFmqgNwjZgnfk59 strict`. I misread the code the first time through as though you had to have a `ledger` to include `strict`, but you don't. Since the word "true" is not "strict", however, it treats that unknown value as the `ledger`, which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: `./rippled account_info r9cZA1mLK5R5Am25ArfXFmqgNwjZgnfk59 strict` works!

Comment: Huzzah! I'm glad to hear it!